# Can't understand this JSON schema from the Swish QR Code API

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to use an API but the documentation is really bad. I got this JSON schema but I don't understand it. What am I supposed to include in the request?

url: https://mpc.getswish.net/qrg-swish/api/v1/prefilled

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```json
{
    "payee":{
        "editable":{
            "editable":"false"
            },
        "swishString":{
            "value":"0721876507"
        }
    },
    "size":600,
    "border":20,
    "transparent":false,
    "format":"png"
}
```

Here's the JSON schema

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Swish pre-filled qr code generator",
    "description": "REST interface to get a QR code that the Swish app will interpret as a pre filled code",
    "definitions": {
        "editable": {
            "description ": "Controls if user can modify this value in Swish app or not",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "editable": {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": false
                }
            }
        },
        "swishString": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "value": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "maxLength": 70
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "value"
            ]
        },
        "swishNumber": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "value": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "value"
            ]
        }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "format": {
            "enum": [
                "jpg",
                "png",
                "svg"
            ]
        },
        "payee": {
            "description": "Payment receiver",
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/editable"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/swishString"
                }
            ]
        },
        "amount": {
            "description": "Payment amount",
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/editable"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/swishNumber"
                }
            ]
        },
        "message": {
            "description": "Message for payment",
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/editable"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/swishString"
                }
            ]
        },
        "size": {
            "description": "Size of the QR code. The code is a square, so width and height are the same. Not required is the format is svg",
            "value": "number",
            "minimum": 300
        },
        "border": {
            "description": "Width of the border.",
            "type": "number"
        },
        "transparent": {
            "description": "Select background color to be transparent. Do not work with jpg format.",
            "type": "boolean"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "format"
    ],
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "required": [
                "payee"
            ]
        },
        {
            "required": [
                "amount"
            ]
        },
        {
            "required": [
                "message"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "maxProperties": 5
}
```

The API should return a QR code.

Comment: How are you fetching the JSON? Please include all relevant code

Comment: I'm fetching it like the first example

Comment: The first example is JSON, not code to fetch the JSON

Comment: I use postman to call the API.

Comment: If you put the JSON Schema and the JSON you created into https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net, you can see there are errors in your data.

Comment: You may want to read http://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step.html and take a look at http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/

Comment: "I don't understand JSON Schema" is a bit broad and vague, which is considered off topic for StackOverflow. If you have any problem understanding a specific part or key word from JSON Schema, please do ask! (I'd recomend deleting this question and re-posting, making sure to include the jsonschema tag as before) =]

Comment: This is wrong: `"editable":"false"`. "editable" is of type `boolean` but you supplied the **string** "false". Change it to `"editable": false`

Comment: Side tip: why don't you play with online validator and read errors carefully + the reading suggested by @Relequestual? E.g. https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I have not taken the time to learn JSON schema, but your example should probably look something like this:

```
{
  "payee": {
    "value": "0721876507",
    "editable": false
  },
  "size": 600,
  "border": 20,
  "transparent": false,
  "format": "png"
}
```

There are other parameters you may choose to utilize:

```
{
  "payee": {
    "value": "1239006032",
    "editable": false
  },
  "message": {
    "value": "LIV",
    "editable": true
  },
  "amount": {
    "value": 100,
    "editable": true
  },
  "format": "png", 
  "size": 300,
  "border": 0,
  "transparent": true
}
```

Honestly, I think the developers behind the Swish APIs are trying to look smart by complicating things. They should, of course, have provided example JSON data instead of forcing consumers to understand their JSON schema. Also, I believe their published schema is wrong. The second example I provided works even though it doesn't validate according to the JSON schema ("Object property count 7 exceeds maximum count of 5").

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal and pretty useless request that returns a valid QR-code

```
{
    "format": "png",
    "size": 300
}
```

And here is a more usable example that works

```
{
    "format": "png",
    "size": 300,
    "transparent": false,
    "amount": {
        "value": 999.99,
        "editable": true
    },
    "payee": {
        "value": "0701000000",
        "editable": false
    },
    "message": {
        "value": "Hello",
        "editable": false
    }
}
```